Conditional probability density function of the parameter $\lambda$, given a data set.
Consider the one-sided conditional exponential distribution:
\begin{equation}
f_X(x|\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{Z(\lambda)}\exp(-\lambda x), 1\leq x\leq 20,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda>0$ and $Z(\lambda)$ is the normalizing constant required to make the area under $f_X(x|\lambda)$ equal unity.
Given $N$ independent values of $x$, namely $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ use Bayes' rule to formulate the conditional probability density function of the parameter $\lambda$, given this data set.
Effort: what I understood from the question is that it wants the following:
\begin{equation}
f_{\lambda|x_1,\dots,x_N}(\lambda|x_1,\dots,x_N)=\frac{[f_{X_1}(x_1|\lambda)f_{X_2}(x_2|\lambda)\dots f_{X_N}(x_N|\lambda)]f_{\lambda}(\lambda)}{f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)\dots f_{X_N}(x_N)}.
\end{equation}
The terms $f_{X_i}(x_i|\lambda)$ can be obtained from the previous distribution. The terms $f_{X_i}(x_i)$ in the denominator are obtained from the regular (unconditional) exponential distribution. What would be $f_\lambda(\lambda)$?
I believe this question is related to the concept of Bayesian inference. So we know our observations $x_1,\dots,x_N$ come from an exponential distribution, but we do not know what the parameter $\lambda$ of that distribution. So this process characterizes how to update the distribution of the random variable $\lambda$, from observed date. Am I correct in my understanding of this question?

Wouldn’t that be a prior?

Yes, you are updating a prior distribution of $\lambda$ to a posterior distribution given the data and $f(\lambda)$ is the prior.
There is a problem with your denominator though. The $X_i$ are not actually independent but rather conditionally independent given $\lambda,$ so while the numerator factors as you wrote, the denominator does not. Instead, the denominator should be the integral over $\lambda$ of the numerator.
In general, evaluating this downstairs integral is hard and it's a common theme to find tricks to simplify or avoid it (and often avoiding by just by declining to do the calculation and ignoring is the way to go because you don't actually need the value some of the time). Most of the time some numerical methods need to come into play... (and note this is nontrivial in the case where there are more than a few parameters since naively numerically integrating by 'adding up boxes' becomes computationally intractable in more than a few dimensions). One old idea that makes things very tidy but is limited in scope is the method of conjugate priors where you use a prior from a parametric family chosen so that the posterior will always be in the same family, and there are generally easy rules for updating the parameters based on the data.
